# Android background support screen sizes

Tags: android, background-image, android-screen-support

I'm creating an Android app and facing an issue, created a background in illustrator 720px*1280px and don't really know where to put it in android, I mean `drawable-ldpi`, `drawable-mdpi`, `drawable-hdpi`, etc.

Comment: BTW, that's probably one big file, if you will add few resized versions, your apk size will grow quickly. Maybe consider to put into image only some details, and build the whole background from some dynamic data (drawable shapes defined in xml), or with API 21+ you can use [SVG with Vector Asset Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html). But if your image contains lot of information, then .png is probably still the best option (or jpg, if the compression doesn't damage it too much).

Answer (score 0):

You have set width and height as wrap_content. Go for giving the static height with with the help of different values folders for different screen sizes. In different files you have to give same dimen name with different values.

```
res/values/dimens.xml(default)
res/values-ldpi/dimens.xml   (240x320 and nearer resolution)
res/values-mdpi/dimens.xml   (320x480 and nearer resolution)
res/values-hdpi/dimens.xml   (480x800, 540x960 and nearer resolution)
res/values-xhdpi/dimens.xml  (720x1280 - Samsung S3, Micromax Canvas HD, etc) 
res/values-xxhdpi/dimens.xml (1080x1920 - Samsung S4, HTC one, etc)
res/values-large/dimens.xml  (480x800)

res/values-large-mdpi/dimens.xml (600x1024)
res/values-sw600dp/dimens.xml  (600x1024)
res/values-sw720dp/dimens.xml  (800x1280)
res/values-xlarge-xhdpi/dimens.xml (2560x1600 - Nexus 10")
res/values-large-xhdpi/dimens.xml  (1200x1920 - Nexus 7"(latest))
```

Comment: Rahul correctly mentioned the sizes of the images. You must follow these and make multiple images. But, if you don'y want to make so many images then you can just make a single image of size res/values-xhdpi/dimens.xml  (720x1280). Android takes the drawables and automatically fixes them for the xhdpi and lower devices. So only a single image can also work for you.

Comment: I think you didn't understund my question or maybe I didn't understund the answer .I want to create multiple background for multiple screen sizes ,I started with creating a background with 720px*1280px but I don't know in which drawable folder i need to put it .I hope I was clear .

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in the official docs

> xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp 
>   large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp 
>  
>   normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp 
>   small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

.

> Note: These minimum screen sizes were not as well defined prior to
>   Android 3.0, so you may encounter some devices that are mis-classified
>   between normal and large. These are also based on the physical
>   resolution of the screen, so may vary across devices—for example a
>   1024x720 tablet with a system bar actually has a bit less space
>   available to the application due to it being used by the system bar.

for more refer link : https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

Just create a folder under res directory named **drawable-xhdpi** and paste your image into that folder.

If you want all sizes images then create other folders named **drawable-ldpi**, **drawable-mdpi** and so on under res directory.

Hope this answers you question.